# Frequent extension data loss with chrome.storage.sync?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am facing a problem with `chrome.storage.sync` is that i lost my extension data many times and this pushed me to ask about the way chrome API works when it comes to storage.

Is this a known problem with `chrome.storage.sync`?

Does `chrome.storage.local` provide a better data presistence?

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some description!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }

}
```

Comment: There's no such problem normally, so it's either a bug or your data exceeds the limits described in the documentation of this API.

Comment: @wOxxOm what type of bugs can delete all data from the storage??..how do i know if the data exceeds the limits..thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Bugs in the browser. 2) See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-sync).

Comment: i get this error in the browser once i open the extension, is this related to the problem??..`VM166:48 This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.`

Comment: Probably not, but you need to investigate what causes it.

Comment: i just discovered that i am using background.js file that set initial value of my data once extension installed, i can't confirm that this is involved in deleting my data since it only works after extension installation but i need to know your opinion `// chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({storedBooks: []})
 });`

Comment: This listener runs each time the extension updates or is reloaded.

Comment: ok i started to suspect it now, i will try to find another way to set initial data in the storage

Comment: This listener has a parameter which you can check to detect the first install. See the documentation.